# Upgrading jclouds to 1.6 (from 1.0), using a CDN

Tags: rackspace-cloud, cloudfiles, jclouds

I am upgrading jclouds from 1.0 to 1.6. In 1.6 the classes and the methods don't match. I need to implement login to CDN and storing file to CDN.

Is there any code that already does this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is some sample code for you to peruse!  Take a look at the [Rackspace CDN example](https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds-examples/blob/master/rackspace/src/main/java/org/jclouds/examples/rackspace/cloudfiles/UploadDirectoryToCDN.java) and run it against the 1.6 release.

Comment: thanks a lot.
before i upload the file to CDN i want to check if the file is already exist there. i tried to check it with : 
 jcloudFilesClient.getObjectInfo(CONTAINER_PUBLISH, name); -crushing on runtime
or  jcloudFilesClient.getObjectMetaData(CONTAINER_PUBLISH, name);-not compiled. do you have any idea??